# What is the best way to define an R function that does not return a value?

Tags: r

The title of the issue says it all but, after searching the web, couldn't find a proper way to define a function in `R` that returns nothing.

As an example, I have an `R` function named `my_r_function` that calls a `C` function named `my_c_function` that returns void. I have codified the R function as follows:

```
my_r_function <- function()
{
   .Call("my_c_function")
}
```

According to the R reference manual, the function returns the value of the last executed statement (in this case, `Call`). Is it possible to have a function that simply returns nothing in `R`?

Comment: You could add a `return(NULL)` at the end of your function. But well... it returns the `NULL`-object then...

Comment: You cannot define a function that doesn't return anything. And you shouldn't. If you believe there is nothing useful to return (perhaps invisibly), you should return `NULL` (perhaps `invisible(NULL)`).

Comment: @Roland: could you please elaborate a bit on `invisible` and the side effects of using it?

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate. The function does what its name says: suppress auto-printing.